# understanding HTTrack actions

Tags: command-line, terminal, internet, offline-files, httrack

i just started using HTTrack . and it offers 5 actions whenever i want to download a website for offline viewing. which are

1 Mirror Web Site(s)
2 Mirror Web Site(s) with Wizard
3 Just Get Files Indicated
4 Mirror ALL links in URLs (Multiple Mirror)
5 Test Links In URLs (Bookmark Test)
0 Quit

i am unaware what each action performs. i would really appreciate if someone could help me out in understanding here. which is the best action among those?

Comment: Still no answer?  wow.